# Helidon Webclient does not seem to work with a proxy

Tags: helidon, helidon-webclient

I am facing some trouble with the WebClient when using proxy, i.e. the code below does not work

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUri("BASEURL").proxy(getProxy()).build();
Single<WebClientResponse> res = webClient.get().path("/MY/SUB/PATH").addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + MY_TOKEN).request();
WebClientResponse webClientRes = res.get();
String resContent = webClientRes.content().as(String.class).get();


public Proxy getProxy(){
    return Proxy.builder().type(Proxy.ProxyType.HTTP).host(host).port(port).password("SECRET_PASSWORD".toCharArray()).username(username).build();
}
```

However the if we use Apache HttpClient the code works (working code below)

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(host, port);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxy), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, "SECRET_PASSWORD"));
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("BASEURL" + "/MY/SUB/PATH");
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + MY_TOKEN);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
String resContent = EntityUtils.toString(httpClient.execute(request).getEntity());
```

could anyone let us know if we are overlooking something basic?
We are using helidon MP 2.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a proxy in WebClient, it will use absolute URI in the request because of changes made in https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/2302 and https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/3438. The use of  absolute URI was implemented because of section 5.1.2 Request-URI in https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html which states:

> The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a
> proxy.

The problem is that some hosts have issue processing a request with absolute URI as they expect relative URI instead. I have encountered while working on issue https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/4644 where my testcase has a client that is connecting to KeyCloak as an OIDC server, and KeyCloak will return a 404 because it cannot handle the absoluteURI.

There is a special Webclient config property called **relative-uris** that you can use to force the request URI to use the relative form rather than absolute. So you can try adding *config()* in your *WebClient.builder()* and set that property like this:

```
.config(Config.create(ConfigSources.create(Map.of("relative-uris", "true")))
```

where *Config* needs to be imported as *io.helidon.config.Config* and *ConfigSources* as *io.helidon.config.ConfigSources*. As an alternative, you can also add something like this in your *application.yaml*:

```
force-relative-uris:
   relative-uris: true
```

and add *config()* in the *WebClient.builder()* like this:

```
.config(config.get("force-relative-uris"))
```

where config is instantiated prior to WebClient.builder() like this:

```
Config config = Config.create();
```

In the upcoming Helidon v2.5.5 (and v3.0.3), there will be a new *relativeUris(boolean relativeUris)* in *WebClient.builder()* so that you don’t have to use *config()* as in my examples above, which is slightly cumbersome.